# SQL Query variable on Table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to perform a query on a Table in SQL but the name of the colums to be retrieved is variable, for example:

```
string[] columns = new string[] { "lastname, firstname, status" };
Dictionary<string, string> columValues = GetColumnValues(userId, columns);
```

Is LINQ a good option to accomplish it? If so please shed some light on this.

Ps. using Sql Server and c#

thanks,
M0dest0.

Comment: why not dynamically create the sqlcommand? or you have to use LINQ?

Comment: @urlreader I think this is what I will have to do. I was thinking that with LINQ should be easier or automatic.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do with EF6 & C# is create a class at runtime which contains your dynamic properties & run an EF6 query with SqlQuery (and create manually the SQL query you need).

search for some examples with this to create a new class at runtime:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

EF6 run sql query:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx